Chinese language chat room frozen
The chat room designated to practice Chinese is frozen http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6586/ 
Can it be unfrozen? 
BTW - I think there should be a way to request this task on chat rooms in general.
UPDATE:
I am not sure why it still says frozen when I access the website. I have tried on two different browsers with no cache.



I'm not sure what you mean by frozen, I just posted a test message. Perhaps it was a temporary problem.

Agree its strange. For me the issue continues as the two new graphics illustrate.

@TommieC., you can try asking on meta.stackexchange.com .

Will do. Thanks for the assist.

It was deleted and frozen, I have unfrozen it. And now it's available. To avoid such things happening in the future, use it! :P
